# Try-runtime error, runtime is NOT compiled with try-runtime feature

Tags: runtime-upgrade, try-runtime

I am struggling with following error, any thoughts what can cause it? I am compiling WASM blob with following command:

```sh
cargo build --release --features try-runtime --package frontier-template-runtime
```

Here is execution of the `try-runtime` binary:

```sh
     Running `target/release/frontier-template-node try-runtime --runtime target/release/wbuild/frontier-template-runtime/frontier_template_runtime.compact.compressed.wasm on-runtime-upgrade live --uri 'ws://localhost:9944'`
2023-09-18 10:40:08 since no at is provided, setting it to latest finalized head, 0x692d7800220955d1c4d12465b1089a3e047e249ba6233f62979969856f37bc79    
2023-09-18 10:40:08 since no prefix is filtered, the data for all pallets will be downloaded    
2023-09-18 10:40:08 scraping key-pairs from remote at block height 0x692d7800220955d1c4d12465b1089a3e047e249ba6233f62979969856f37bc79    
2023-09-18 10:40:08 Querying a total of 587 keys from prefix , splitting among 10 threads, 59 keys per thread    
2023-09-18 10:40:08 adding data for hashed prefix: , took 0s    
2023-09-18 10:40:08 adding data for hashed key: 3a636f6465    
2023-09-18 10:40:08 adding data for hashed key: 26aa394eea5630e07c48ae0c9558cef7f9cce9c888469bb1a0dceaa129672ef8    
2023-09-18 10:40:08 adding data for hashed key: 26aa394eea5630e07c48ae0c9558cef702a5c1b19ab7a04f536c519aca4983ac    
2023-09-18 10:40:08 initialized state externalities with storage root 0xfb8262147a2cd552fc2df2b136c085bc81068a62569ea365eb9542a0788bd57c and state_version V1    
2023-09-18 10:40:08 original spec: RuntimeString::Owned("Frontier Node")-2, code hash: a3b1ff254b152844bbda18d12b3d4507d8530a59d9a1127e10d2bc59af2d3f40    
2023-09-18 10:40:08 new spec: RuntimeString::Owned("Frontier Node")-2, code hash: 6552cf3323ecf6230ec62fd93f8db67aea59172ea7c92bf976ac58b157e50111    
Error: Input("given runtime is NOT compiled with try-runtime feature!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I guess I found a solution. Implementation of `frame_try_runtime::TryRuntime<Block>` was outside of `impl_runtime_apis!` section, so it was not detected, now it is moved:

```rust
impl_runtime_apis! {
    #[cfg(feature = "try-runtime")]
    impl frame_try_runtime::TryRuntime<Block> for Runtime {
        fn on_runtime_upgrade(checks: frame_try_runtime::UpgradeCheckSelect) -> (Weight, Weight) {
            let weight = Executive::try_runtime_upgrade(checks).unwrap();
            (weight, BlockWeights::get().max_block)
        }

        fn execute_block(
            block: Block,
            state_root_check: bool,
            checks: bool,
            select: frame_try_runtime::TryStateSelect,
        ) -> Weight {
            Executive::try_execute_block(block, state_root_check, checks, select).unwrap()
        }
     }
}
```